# How can I fix encoding errors in a string in python

Tags: python, encoding

I have a python script as a subversion pre-commit hook, and I encounter some problems with UTF-8 encoded text in the submit messages. For example, if the input character is "å" the output is "?\195?\165". What would be the easiest way to replace those character parts with the corresponding byte values? Regexp doesn't work as I need to do processing on each element and merge them back together.

code sample:

```
infoCmd = ["/usr/bin/svnlook", "info", sys.argv[1], "-t", sys.argv[2]]
info = subprocess.Popen(infoCmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
info = info.replace("?\\195?\\166", "æ")
```

Comment: It'll probably help if you post the code that is causing the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same things in my code and you should be able to use:

...
u_changed_path = unicode(changed_path, 'utf-8')
...

When using the approach above, I've only run into issues with characters like line feeds and such.  If you post some code, it could help.